# Not able to configure Django project with multiple apps

Tags: python, django, django-settings

Here is my project structure:

```
Project
    |_Application_one
    |_Application_two
    |_DjangoProject (Now has been deleted)
    |_manage.py
    |_settings.py
    |_urls.py
    |_templates
           |_home.html
```

I want to load the content of `home.html` when someone put address `127.0.0.1:8000\home.html` but whenever i am running the `Django` server, It is throwing following error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'DjangoProject.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named DjangoProject.settings
```

Code of `manage.py`

```
import os
import sys

try:
   import settings
except ImportError:
   import sys
  sys.stderr.write("Error: Can't Find the files settings.py in the directory containing %r. It appears you've customized things.\nYou'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.\n(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)\n" % __file__)
  sys.exit(1)

if __name__== "__main__":
   import settings
   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
   from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I want to load settings.py (outer one) but it is asking for DjangoProject.settings.py. How should i access settings.py?

**Edit**

wsgi.py file

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:/Users/test/Desktop/project/manage.py", line 18, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'DjangoProject.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named DjangoProject.settings
```

Comment: Check the file name first. In your listed directory structure above, it is called setting.py rather than settings.py.

Comment: @DavidM It was typo mistake, Confirmed from pycharm

Comment: off topic, but you are uselessly importing `sys` a second time within the `except `block`

Comment: @AmitPal You don't have the `wsgi.py` file which is generated in django projects?

Comment: Is there anything in the code that calls manage.py that sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable?

Comment: @DavidM No, I am running this project from Pycharm.

Comment: Move that file (`wsgi.py`) also out of the DjangoProject directory and change the `os.environ` statement in it to reflect new path to settings.

Comment: @mu無 Where i have to change the `os.environ`?

Comment: Inside the `path/DjangoProject/DjangoProject/wsgi.py` file, there is `os.environ.setdefault` statement, which refers to the settings file path. 1) Move that file out to `path/DjangoProject/wsgi.py`, 2) change the path to settings in it. Let me know if that works

Comment: Done! Still the same error

Comment: Can you try removing the try except lock with wsgi.py in tact? I think the issue might be with importing settings without `__main__` in that try block.

Comment: @mu無 check content of wsgi.py file

Comment: Full traceback where?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams check the trace

Comment: Does `$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` have any value before you try to set it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams If we create a django project From `pycharm` then why is it using application (first applicaiton) setting.py?

Comment: I don't know. Did you try reconfiguring Pycharm?

Comment: Nothing happend, Anyway @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams could it be possible for you to give me sample Django project with above structure?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your current structure. The problem you're having is not caused by the structure.